# Unix one-liner to quote all words on a line

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a text file which has lines consisting of words (separated by spaces) and I want to put quotes around all of the words.

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur 
adipisicing elitsed do  

eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut
  labore et dolore magna 
aliqua
```

Should become:

```
"Lorem" "ipsum" "dolor" "sit" "amet"
"consectetur"
"adipisicing" "elitsed" "do"

"eiusmod" "tempor"
"incididunt" "ut"
  "labore" "et" "dolore" "magna"
"aliqua"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/"&"/g' filename > newname
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("\"%s\" ",$i);printf("\n");}' filename > newname
```

Comment: Thanks! The sed works for me on OSX. I haven't tried the awk.

Comment: @jlliagre Can you explain why do we need 2 `[^ ][^ ]` in the above sed command please?

Comment: @TonyBarganski It's been a log time! I guess my goal was to ignore single characters words, possibly empty lines ending with CR-LF but the awk version is more reliable.

Comment: @jlliagre Wow, I hadn't noticed the date - amazing that you replied. 
Find at least two characters or more - makes perfect sense now, thanks.

Comment: @TonyBarganski I had a closer look to my sed script and actually, it doesn't ignores single character strings, the second block being optional. Two blocks are there for empty lines not to be quoted.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/[^ ]\+/"&"/g' filename > newname
```

or, to update the file in-place

```
sed -i 's/[^ ]\+/"&"/g' filename
```

Comment: Neither version works for me. The first version: output file is same as input file (no quotes were added). Second version: I'm getting an "undefined label" error from sed. I'm on OSX Lion, if that affects things.

Comment: glenn - nice sed, works fine for me in ubuntu .....
dsg - try [^ ]+ instead of [^ ]\+.

Comment: @bryan -- no dice.

Comment: OSX is BSD based, that sed command doesn't work the same as GNU. One article I read mentioned you can't escape characters there as you can in GNU, the other mentioned the -i is interpreted slightly different as well.